# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'NoneType' and 'float'

Tags: python

Не могу понять почему выдаёт ошибку `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'NoneType' and 'float'`.

Код:

```
x = float(input('Подставьте число x: '))
y = float(input('Подставьте число y: '))
if y == 0:
    print('Выражение не вычисляется')
else:    
 print (5+x/x**3+y**3) - (math.tan(x)*(3+x/y))
```

Comment: Функция print ничего не возвращает, а значит результат вызова функции `print (5+x/x**3+y**3)` имеет значение `None`, а вы из этого None почему-то пытаетесь что-то вычитать

Answer (score 0):

`print` это отдельная функция и функции вызываются вот так: `print()`, вы проводите вычисления, но их результат не выводите.

```
import math


x, y = map(float, input().split()) #маппингом можно сделать ввод через пробел 

if y == 0:
    print('Выражение не вычисляется')
else:    
    print((5+x/x**3+y**3) - (math.tan(x)*(3+x/y)))
```

ввод:

```
1 1
```

вывод:

```
0.7703691013803908
```